# r - source script file that contains unicode (Farsi) character

Tags: r, unicode

write the text below in a buffer and save it as a `.r` script:

```
letters_fa <- c('الف','ب','پ','ت','ث','ج','چ','ح','خ','ر','ز','د')
```

then try these lines to `source()` it:

```
script <- "path/to/script.R"
file(script,
     encoding = "UTF-8") %>%
  readLines() # works fine

file(script,
     encoding = "UTF-8") %>%
  source() # works fine

source(script) # the Farsi letters in the environment are misrepresented

source(script,
       encoding = "UTF-8") # gives error
```

The last line throws error. I tried to debug it and I believe there is a bug in the `source` function, in the following lines:

```
...
loc <- utils::localeToCharset()[1L]
...
```

The error occurs at `.Internal(parse(` line.

```
...
exprs <- if (!from_file) {
      if (length(lines)) 
        .Internal(parse(stdin(), n = -1, lines, "?", 
          srcfile, encoding))
      else expression()
    }
    else .Internal(parse(file, n = -1, NULL, "?", srcfile, 
      encoding))
...
```

The exact error is:

```
Error in source(script, encoding = "UTF-8") : 
  script.R:2:17: unexpected INCOMPLETE_STRING
1: #' @export
2: letters_fa <- c('
                   ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to either change the OS Locale to a native Locale (e.g. Persian in this case) or use R built-in function `Sys.setlocale(locale="Persian")` to change an R session native Locale.

Answer (score 0):

Use `source` without specifying the encoding, and then modify the vector's encoding with `Encoding`:

```
source(script)
letters_fa
#  [1] "Ø§Ù„Ù\u0081" "Ø¨"     "Ù¾"     "Øª"     "Ø«"    
#  [6] "Ø¬"     "Ú†"     "Ø­"     "Ø®"     "Ø±"    
# [11] "Ø²"     "Ø¯"
Encoding(letters_fa) <- "UTF-8"
letters_fa
# [1] "الف" "ب"   "پ"   "ت"   "ث"   "ج"   "چ"   "ح"   "خ"   "ر"   "ز"   "د"
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. However, I don't want to use it in this way. I have many files with Farsi characters; I routinely source these files which contain many (not just a single) variables with character strings.